# How to force parent Window be on top of child Window

Tags: qt, qml

Here is my sample code:

```
Window{
  id: root
  title: "Hello"
  Window{
    id: child
    title: "Wnd1"
  }
}
```

here is the result when i activate click the root:

[image: here is the result when i activate click the root]

Is there any way to force root be on top of child when I activate it?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I have found a solution, it is looks not very elegant but it works

```
Window {
  QtObject{
    property Window child: Window {
      visible: true
    }
  }
  visible: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of appropriate flags, for example [Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum)

```
Window {
    width: 600
    height: 400
    title: qsTr("Parent window")
    visible: true
    flags: Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint

    Window {
        width: 300
        height: 200
        title: qsTr("Child window")
        visible: true
    }
}
```

But what a reason do do that? You will not be able to communicate with the child window.

Answer (score -1):

it works on windows for me:

```
Window{
    property Window child: ChildWindow{}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**